# what is the best way to create chat api(rest webservices) using spring

Tags: java, spring, chat, spring-restcontroller

i want to create a chat api(rest webservices) with spring . the api needs to support for all mobile platforms (ios, andriod , ... etc).
can any one please suggest what is best way to build this in java.

Comment: Have a look at http://g00glen00b.be/spring-angular-sockjs/ and http://www.theotherian.com/2014/03/spring-boot-websockets-stomp-chat.html tutorials. Regarding mobile platform support it will mostly be affected by how you handle your view

Comment: Hi Balwinder, thanks for your comment.

Comment: is there any existing libraries which supports group chats ?

Comment: Not sure about group chats. But you can use https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere as Realtime Client Server Framework

Comment: thanks Balwinder, am new to mobile apps. actually we need to build a application like whatsapp group chat in the app will call the webservices and the webservices need to do the push notification to all group members.can you please suggest on this

Comment: Basically, your server side app will hold the business logic which will be exposed through webservice APIs. These APIs will be consumed and used by your mobile app. The mobile apps will be coded to provided user interface and capture user actions. Based on the action, appropriate webservice API will be called for sending across messages. The group chats will also be managed by your server side code.